# Send SOAP Request using WSDL reference

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

```
        XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();
        SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
        xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
        xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
    <soap:Body>
    <COMPANY>abc</COMPANY>
    <PASSWORD>xyz</PASSWORD>
    <USER>UTrack</USER>
    " + vtrackenv +
    "</soap:Body>" +
    "</soap:Envelope>");
```

Data in vtrackenv comes from a loop every time it iterates and build a soap envelope.

```
                vtrackenv += "<VTRACK><item>" +
                "<TL_REGISTRATION_NO> " + regNo + @"</TL_REGISTRATION_NO>" +
                "<ALERT_DATE> " + Datemodi + @"</ALERT_DATE>" +
                "<ALERT_TIME> " + timemodi + @"</ALERT_TIME>" +
                    "<ALERT_TYPE> " + typealert + @" </ALERT_TYPE>" +
                    "<SAP_CODE> " + codesap + @"</SAP_CODE>" +
                    "<COMPANY> " + companyname + @"</COMPANY>" +
                    "<ALERT_DAY> " + daymodi + @"</ALERT_DAY>" +
                    "<LOCATION_NAME> " + locname + @" </LOCATION_NAME>" +
                    "<LOCATION_CITY> " + cty + @"</LOCATION_CITY>" +
                    "<RL_CODE></RL_CODE>" +
                    "<LOCATION_TYPE></LOCATION_TYPE>" +
                    "<LOCATION_COORDINATES_LAT>" + lat + @"</LOCATION_COORDINATES_LAT>" +
                    "<LOCATION_COORDINATES_LON>" + ilong + @"</LOCATION_COORDINATES_LON>" +
                    "<COMMENTS></COMMENTS>" +
                    "</item>" +
                    "</VTRACK>";
```

now I need to send the final XML which has been created to the specified URI mentioned in wsdl and also I have the credentials with me.

```
   HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()
        {
            HttpWebRequest Req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://");

            Req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            Req.Headers.Add(@"SOAP:Action");
            Req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            Req.Accept = "text/xml";
            Req.Method = "POST";

            return Req;
        }
        HttpWebRequest request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

      using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {

                SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);

            }
        }
```

**error:**

> ((System.Net.ConnectStream)stream).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException))
>   ((System.Net.ConnectStream)stream).Position' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException))

Comment: It looks like somewhere something is trying to obtain the `Length` of the request stream, which you can't, because it's write-only. But why are you going through all this hassle of writing a string to an HTTP request body? You don't need the `XmlDocument`, you don't need the `MemoryStream` and you definitely aren't using a WSDL-generated client as you claim in the title, which would make this way easier anyway.

Comment: I'm using the WSDL generated Client and it has the method to send the packet with credentials & an array .
I asked the my client he said WSDL is for the reference only you just have to make a HTTP web request to the specific URI and send the data in XML. That's it